# Xamarin iOS, FileNotFound for Bundle Resources

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I keep getting the error like this:

```
Error       System.IO.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Nathaniel/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/EagleEyePrism.iOS/7b66664107c017167463bbde19c6a2f4/obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/upload_blue.png does not exist
File name: '/Users/Nathaniel/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/EagleEyePrism.iOS/7b66664107c017167463bbde19c6a2f4/obj/iPhone/Debug/optimized/upload_blue.png'
  at System.IO.File.Copy (System.String sourceFileName, System.String destFileName, System.Boolean overwrite) [0x00193] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2018-08/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/File.cs:111 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.CopyFile (System.String source, System.String target, System.String targetItemSpec) [0x0002d] in <cd319828b05749ae9de0c80034a6d2bc>:0 
  at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.SmartCopyTaskBase.Execute () [0x000b6] in <cd319828b05749ae9de0c80034a6d2bc>:0    EagleEyePrism.iOS
```

It doesn't matter what file it is.  If I remove upload_blue.png, it throws an error on the next Resource.

I have tried everything.  I have deleted the Xamarin cache on the Mac, I've deleted AppData\Local\Xamarin on the PC, it simply will not compile.
If I set all the BundleResources to Embedded Resources, it will compile and run, but then none of my image collateral gets displayed.

I've scoured the internet for hours trying to solve this problem.

I'm running the latest XCode on the Mac, with MacOS Mojave, and Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 on the PC.

Comment: Your images are inside the iOS project or Shared project?
if is it inside your resources folder on iOS project you need to set the build action to BundleResource, if it is inside the shared project you will need to create an extension like:
https://gist.github.com/aimore/5b2048a1f2c29f75726567dbb53b8728
If none work, try adding images to an asset catalog image set:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos

Comment: Yeah.  They're all set to Bundle Resources, but nothing works.  It's like it's not copying the files from the PC to the Mac.  And I don't understand why.  These are both relatively new machines, running the latest software.  Yes, they're in the iOS project.

Comment: BTW, I tried building the solution straight from the Mac, and I get the same error (the location is different, but the error is the same) ... I even tried enabling full-disk access for Xcode.  I'm not sure what's going on, here.  I don't want to use xcassets ... I just want to add these bundled resources.

Also, it should be mentioned that I have other, non-image bundled resources, as well.

Comment: Okay.  I excluded ALL .png image resources from the Resources directory, and marked all other files Bundled Resource, and it compiled, just fine.  I'm going to try something else, I'll keep you posted.  I feel like I am a step closer to the solution.

Comment: I solved it by disabling the Optimize PNG images option in the iOS Build Options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by disabling the Optimize PNG images option in the iOS Build Options

Comment: You're quite welcome. :-) It saved my day, too!